# shell script cut, variable instead of number in -f[]

Tags: shell, variables, cut

I am parsing a long string, `$STRING`, and I can't change `cut -d} -f4` to  `cut -d} -f'$FIELD'`

```
ID="notnull"
FIELD="4"
while [[ ! -z $ID ]]
do
  ID=`echo $STRING |  cut -d} -f4 | cut -d'"' -f4`
  echo "ID:" $ID
  FIELD=`expr $COUNTER + 4`
  echo $COUNTER
done
```

I need to change this for iteration. try use '  "  ` { [ but every time error(( 
And then my while will work for for moment, when variable ID will be empty

Comment: I get the feeling there is a much better way to parse `$STRING`. `}` and `"` aren't typically used as field delimiters, so I assume you are using some ad-hoc splitting to get to the text you want. Regular expressions may be simpler to use (without having to spawn so many processes).

Comment: Could you give an example of `$STRING` input ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use double quotes:

```
ID=`echo $STRING |  cut -d} -f"$FIELD" | cut -d'"' -f4`
```

Comment: +1: And also fix the `FIELD=$(expr $COUNTER + 4)` to `FIELD=$(expr $FIELD + 4)` or `((FIELD+=4))` in `bash` or `FIELD=$(( $FIELD + 4 ))` in POSIX shells. You should always use the `$(…)` in preference to back quotes, too.